# Continuous audio download stream

Tags: audio, download, server, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I'm looking to set up a server which will read from a some audio input device and serve that audio continuously to clients.

I don't need the audio to be necessarily be played by the client in real time I just want to be able for the client to start downloading from the point at which they join and then leave again.

So say the server broadcasts 30 seconds of audio data, a client could connect 5 seconds in and download 10 seconds of it (giving them 0:05 - 0:15).

Can you do this kind of partial download over TCP starting at whenever the client connects and end up with a playable audio file?

Sorry if this question is a bit too broad and not a 'how do a set variable x to y' kinda question. Let me know if there's a better forum to to post this in.

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect the concepts of file and connection.  They're not related.  A TCP connection simply supports the reliable transfer of data.  Nothing more.  What your application chooses to send over that connection is its business, so you need to set your application in a way that it sends the data you want.

It sounds like what you want is a simple HTTP progressive internet radio stream, which is commonly provided by SHOUTcast and Icecast servers.  I recommend Icecast to get started.  The user connects, they get a small buffer of a few second in front to get them started (optional), and when they disconnect, that's it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I bought up the TCP connection as I know I want the entire file for the period they are connected to be downloaded. I'll take a look at icecast and SHOUTcast again (I had ran across them but didn't give them enough time), thanks. Maybe what I'm actually asking for is how to do theoretically never ending file downloads from a server. Maybe something like twitter does to subscribe to a stream over http https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview